# HTML page won't load after removing a script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Somehow my page won't load if this script `<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>` is not in the code.

This is the only script that requires to be loaded from URL.

These are all the js scripts I have included.

```
        <!-- Javascript files -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.inview.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.shuffle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js?v=2"></script>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

I don't use the Vimeo player anymore, so that script is pretty much useless, yet when I remove it, the page won't load.

It just stays in the loading animation

[image]
I also tried replacing that script with

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

but the page still wont load.

it won't show anything in the console too.

Since the preloader is the only thing that loads when the script is missing, I decided to edit the question and upload the preloader code

```
        <!-- Preloader -->
    <div id="tt-preloader">
        <div id="pre-status">
            <div class="preload-placeholder"></div>
        </div>
  </div>


    #tt-preloader {
    background: #FFF;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#pre-status,
.preload-placeholder {
    background-image: url(../images/preloader.gif);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 200px;
}

.preload-placeholder {
    background: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 65%;
}
```

EDIT 2: decided to remove the preloader entirely and the site seems to work well, removed the script too and it connects perfectly.

But I want to have the preloader in, so it can load few stuff before the user gets to explore the site

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: literally nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Along with js there also have HTML and CSS markup for the preloader the js is used to fadeout the animation after the page loads.

Comment: the preloader is just a gif, not an animation.

Comment: My mistake, I mean to say preloader